# Why does the deletion of *.dll.refresh file have no affect?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

The *.dll.refresh file tells visual studio about the class library location but whenever I delete it the application still works in debugging mode.

Why is this? Is the location not needed?

Answer (score 3):

Because that's only a pointer to the referenced DLL.

It is used to copy the DLL to the *bin* location, but if you already copied the DLL, then deleting the *.refresh* file won't affect Visual Studio

If you delete the DLL from the *bin* folder and the _*.refresh_ file then you would get compilation errors if you try to access the types defined in the referenced DLL

Answer (score 2):

dll.refresh files gives the path of the DLL in question to tell visual studio where to find it. They will be created each time you add a reference to the project.

They normally appear when you are using a project type that does not create a standard Visual Studio project file, as normally paths to referenced DLLs would go in there.

```
Their role ends once DLL gets loaded in your project. Hence you will not get any error
 when you delete *.dll.refresh files from your project.
```